# How to extend catalog_product_view.xml for a specific product type?

Tags: magento2, frontend, extend, custom-product-type, catalog-prodct-view.xml

I created a new product type, and I want to create a product page in the frontend. How can I customize catalog_product_view.xml without affecting other product types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **You need to override the layout like this.**

```
catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml -> Simple Product

catalog_product_view_type_virtual.xml -> Virtual Product

catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml -> Configurable Product

catalog_product_view_type_downloadable.xml -> Downloadable Product

catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml -> Bundle Product

catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml -> Grouped Product 

catalog_product_view_type_custom.xml -> Custom Product Type
```

> After updating the product layout in the product view. Then you can maintain product design by updating another layout also.

**Example: Shopping Cart**

```
checkout_cart_configure_type_{TYPE}.
```

> Please check the default file: *vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_configure_type_simple.xml*
> Here they update the layout  You also should to use this for your custom type.

```
vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_configure_type_configurable.xml
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_configure_type_simple.xml
vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_configure_type_bundle.xml
```

**Cart Item Rendererd**

```
vendor/magento//module-configurable-product/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_review_item_renderers.xml -> Configurable Product
vendor/magento//module-downloadable/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_review_item_renderers.xml -> Downloadable Product
vendor/magento//module-bundle/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_review_item_renderers.xm -> Bundle Product
vendor/magento//module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_review_item_renderers.xml -> All Product
vendor/magento//module-grouped-product/view/frontend/layout/checkout_onepage_review_item_renderers.xml -> Group Product
```

You need to create if your layout is not loaded proper in cart item. Please use the default file as a reference.

If you need to show your layout in PDF and order all section there are many files you need to create and update it.

**Example: Print Creditmemo**

**Reference Files**

```
vendor/magento//module-grouped-product/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print_creditmemo_renderers.xml -> Group Product
vendor/magento//module-bundle/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print_creditmemo_renderers.xml -> Bundle Product
vendor/magento//module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print_creditmemo_renderers.xm -> All Product
vendor/magento//module-downloadable/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print_creditmemo_renderers.xml -> Downloadable Product
```

> Sample Code

```
<referenceBlock name="sales.order.print.creditmemo.renderers">
    <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Item\Renderer\DefaultRenderer" name="sales.order.print.creditmemo.renderers.custom" as="custom" 
           template="VendorName_ModuleName::order/creditmemo/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

**There are many files that need to update if you show your custom product everywhere in the store. If you did not find any file for a particular layout please add comments or content to me. or You can get it in core module**

Comment: I would also add that you should create a layout file `checkout_cart_configure_type_{{TYPE}}.xml`, in order to manage the product view page when edited from the cart. Inside it, call the following instruction : `<update handle="catalog_product_view_type_{{TYPE}}"/>`, replacing {{TYPE}} with your custom type name. Take a look at the file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_configure_type_simple.xml` for more info

Comment: @Cladiuss You are right you can feel free to edit my post and add your points there or you can also add your post here.

Comment: Done, I also added some explaination about where this magic happens.

Answer (score 2):

As already said in @Msquare answer, there are native handlers created by Magento for each product types.

There are created with this template : `catalog_product_view_type_{{TYPE}}`, where {{TYPE}} is your custom type name (which has been defined in your `product_types.xml` file).

For a custom type named "custom", you can create a file called  `catalog_product_view_type_custom.xml` where you can add your specific layout instructions.

The same process happens when editing a product in your shopping cart : Magento will create handlers for each product types with this template : `checkout_cart_configure_type_{{TYPE}}`.

So you will also need to create a file called `checkout_cart_configure_type_custom.xml`, in which you can call the first handle name :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="catalog_product_view_type_custom"/>
    <body/>
</page>
```

Take a look at the file `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_configure_type_simple.xml` for a example.

---

**Explaination**

This dynamic handles are added in the `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View::initProductLayout` method, with this specific instruction :

```
$resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $product->getTypeId()], null, false);
```

This method is called both in the Catalog Product View controller, and in the Checkout Cart Configure controller, which is why they both have those specific handles.

Note : The whishlist module also uses this method to create those specifics handles when configuring a whishlist item. They will look like : `whishlist_index_configure_type_{{TYPE}}`.

Answer (score 1):

For example new product type is `customtype`, file layout name is `catalog_product_view_customtype`.

You can use event name `layout_load_before` for load this layout, you will check the product detail page if it is product type `customtype` => you will load layout `catalog_product_view_customtype`.

In **etc/frontend/events.xml**:

```
<event name="layout_load_before">
    <observer name="custom_layout_load_option" instance="Module\Custom\Observer\Layout\Load"/>
</event>
```

In **Load.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Module\Custom\Observer\Layout;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class Load implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected RequestInterface $request;
    protected ProductFactory $productFactory;
    public function __construct
    (
        RequestInterface $request,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $fullActionName = $observer->getEvent()->getFullActionName(); // you get layout name here
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        $handler = '';
        if ($fullActionName == 'catalog_product_view') { // if it true, continue check product type
            // get product id by param
            $productId = $this->request->getParam('id');
            // get product type using productId
            $type = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId, 'entity_id')->getTypeId();
            if ($type) {
                $handler = 'catalog_product_view_customtype';
            }
        }
        if ($handler) {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle($handler);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this might work, there is a natively a layout handler created by Magento for each product type : `catalog_product_view_type_{{TYPE}}`. You are also reloading the product from the database, instead of using the repository which will load it from the cache.